# proof that odd polynomial has root

Tags: calculus

I'm an Engineer (so blindingly obvious things to Mathematicians are not to me) trying to understand mathematics after applying it for many years. So I'm slowly reading Spivak's Calculus on a journey to read some basic Mathematics degree material.

I have finally gotten stuck on theorem 9 proof see extract below from the chapter Three Hard Theorems.

1) I do not understand how $\overset{n terms}{\frac{1}{2n} + \ldots + \frac{1}{2n}} = 1/2$ in the proof.
2) I'm also not sure why $|x| > 2n|a_n-1|,\ldots,2n|a_0|$,

Any help appreciated.

[image: a busy cat]
[image: a busier cat]

Comment: (1) $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2n} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n} = n \frac{1}{2n} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: There are n terms. $n\frac{1}{2n} = \frac{1}{2}$. Also they are claiming that they are choosing some random $|x|$ such that it is larger than the values they are indicating.

Comment: Odd powers maintain the sign, so as *x* goes to $\pm\infty$, so does the polynomial. But the graphic is continuous, so what does this say about its intersection with the real axis?

Answer (score 1):

The condition

$$|x|>1,2n|a_{n-1}|,\ldots,2n|a_0|$$
is just a choice aims to guarentee that
$$f(x)=x^n\left(1+\frac{a_{n-1}}{x}+\cdots+\frac{a_0}{x^n}\right)$$ be positive. Notice that this is possible and just we can take for example $|x|$ is the maximum of these reals plus $1$.

For your first question:
$$\underbrace{\frac1{2n}+\cdots+\frac1{2n}}_{n\;\text{times}}=n\times \frac1{2n}=\frac12$$

Comment: "Notice that this is possible and just we can take for example |x| is the maximum of these reals plus 1." I'm not sure i understand this, could you rephrase?

Comment: I meant that we can take 
$$|x|=\max(1,2n|a_{n-1}|,\ldots,2n|a_0|)+1$$

Answer (score 0):

As an Engineer, you should appreciate when I tell you that they're reinventing too much of the wheel. You should build on what you know. You have to assume the Intermediate Value Theorem, which is a big deal. So, why not short-cut some of the confusion and assume properties of limits that you know from Calculus, too. For example,
$$
                  \lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}\frac{p(x)}{x^{n}}=1.
$$
So, there exists $R > 0$ such that $|p(x)/x^{n}-1| < 1/2$ for $x > R$, or
$$
               1/2 < p(x)/x^{n} < 3/2,\;\;\; x > R\\
                       \implies 1/2 < p(2R)/(2R)^{n} < 3/2\\
                       \implies p(2R) > 0.
$$
Similarly, there exists $R' > 0$ such that $|p(x)/x^{n}-1| < 1/2$ for $x < -R'$, and you get $p(-2R') < 0$. Now apply the Intermediate Value Theorem because nobody wants to re-invent that wheel unless absolutely necessary.